# Configure Visual Studio 2008 to use IIS6 on Server 2003

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have Visual Studio 2008, Windows Server 2003 Enterprise with IIS6 installed.
I don't want to use the local IIS for anything. I want to configure Visual Studio to always use the IIS 6 on the Server 2003. I have full admin rights to both the workstation and the server.

Answer (score 0):

Project | Properties, Web tab | Servers | Use Local IIS Web server